# Object to object mapping in .Net 2.0

Tags: .net

I wonder if anyone can recommend an alternative to Automapper that will work in .NET2.0.

I have a dll which describes a reasonably complex structure. The dll sits at both ends of webservice however when the data is retrieved through the webservice, the namespaces prevent direct mapping of the object so I am having to resort to coding a mapping class.

I incorporated Automapper and it does exactly as I want but it won't work with .NET2.0. I need to use .NET2.0 as there are several hundred remote machines which will run the client software and they are limited to .NET2.0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you move to .Net 3.0 at least? Using WCF, you can share a common DLL of DataContract objects, allowing you to reuse strictly the same object.

Comment: Can't use anything but .NET2.0. Might need to use Mono and also .NET Compact (for CE5.0) too so i'm trying to make the solution is simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is 2.0, I'm guessing this is a regular wsdl-based web-service, working via `XmlSerializer` (unlike WCF which uses `DataContractSerializer` by default). If this is the case, you *should* be able to use `XmlSerializer` twice:

```
FromType fromObj = ...;
ToType toObj;
using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    new XmlSerializer(typeof(FromType)).Serialize(ms, fromObj);
    ms.Position = 0;
    toObj = (ToType) new XmlSerializer(typeof(ToType)).Deserialize(ms);
}
```

Perhaps not ideal, but it should work as long as the types are compatible.

Frustratingly, the WCF tooling has inbuilt support for re-using existing type definitions, to avoid duplication like this. But that is 3.0, obviously.

Comment: Thanks Marc, Tried this however the conversion is only partial since child structures are not mapped correctly. Something to do with namespace reference in the source xml?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the structure complexity, you *could* use reflection to get the list of properties of your first object and set associated values to the second object properties with an identical name.

If your structure has only simple properties, it'll be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

In this case Reflection is your best friend.

Below is a rough implementation of a property copier. You just need to new up an instance of the target type and pass it to this along with the source instance which has all the property values set.

**edit**: as Marc has noted, this will only do the trick in terms of trivial property mapping. Take it with a grain of salt.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public static class ReflectionHelper
    {
        public static void CopyPropertyValues(object source, object target)
        {
            if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
            if (target == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("target");

            var sourceType = source.GetType();
            var targetType = target.GetType();
            var sourceProperties = sourceType.GetProperties();

            foreach (var sourceProperty in sourceProperties)
            {
                if (sourceProperty.CanRead)
                {
                    var targetProperties = targetType.GetProperties();

                    foreach (var targetProperty in targetProperties)
                    {
                        if (targetProperty.Name == sourceProperty.Name &&
                            targetProperty.PropertyType == sourceProperty.PropertyType)
                        {
                            if (targetProperty.CanWrite)
                            {
                                var value = sourceProperty.GetValue(source, null);

                                targetProperty.SetValue(target, value, null);
                            }

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only work for simple values. In most real cases, you are likely to have to handle lists, arrays, dictionaries, etc - and you are likely to have to re-map sub-objects (which will be changing type at the same time), along with re-mapped inheritance.